# how to fix this ERROR: Start vertex was not found

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, error

I am attempting to make an SQL selection but receive an error. My statement:

```
SELECT *
 FROM network
 JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM shortest_path('
 SELECT gid AS id,
 start_id::int4 AS source,
 end_id::int4 AS target,
 "length"::float8 AS cost
 FROM network',
 10,
 12,
 false,
 false)) AS route
 ON
 network.gid = route.edge_id;
```

The error:

```
ERROR:  Start vertex was not found.
********** Error **********

ERROR: Start vertex was not found.
SQL state: XX000
```

Comment: The question is poorly written. You must explain in detail what you are trying to achieve or expecting from a given code. Please explain `shortest_path` function. Which Db are you using and dataset? Most probably the error is there is no vertex in the dataset with source value 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT count(*) FROM network WHERE start_id = 10` to make sure your start vertex exists.

Additional note: you're using `shortest_path` function, so your version of pgRouting seems to be 1.x. I recommend you to upgrade to pgRouting 2.0.